# Unexpected duplicate key exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm seeing a weird behavior with Spring Boot 2.0.4 + Hibernate.

I have an entity including a randomly generated code. If the generated code is already set for another entity, a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown as expected. This way the loop can try again with a new code which hopefully is not used. When this happens, the loop continues, a new code is generated and the call to `saveAndFlush()` throws the same exception again saying that the original code that caused the problem (previous iteration) is already used (duplicate). However, I'm setting a new code now, not the one the exception mentions.

The only thing I can think of is that Hibernate doesn't remove the operation from the "queue" so when the second call to `saveAndFlush()` happens, it still tries to perform the first save and then the new one. Obviously, the first save fails as during the first iteration. Maybe I'm wrong, but then what is going on here?

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int code;

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    //Other properties

}

@Transactional
public void myFunction() {
    boolean saved = false;
    do {
        int code = /* Randomly generated code */;
        if(entity == null) {
            entity = new Entity(code, /* other properties */);
        } else {
            entity.setCode(code);
        }

        try {
            entity = myRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
            saved = true;
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            /* Ignore so that we can try again */
        }
    } while(!saved);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If I replace `saveAndFlush()` by `save()`, the issue disappears. I saw somewhere that doing a save after a previous save that failed may be problematic if `flush()` is also called. This is exactly my case. However, I don't understand why it is a problem. The only reason I call `saveAndFlush()` instead of `save()` is to catch the duplicate key exception. Using `save()`, if Hibernate doesn't perform the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` directly, the exception is thrown during the flush occurring just before the transaction is committed which is not really what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restart your transaction in such a scenario, as the error is already bound to the transaction context/session.

So instead, put the retry logic outside of the transaction boundary, or if you need to maintain integrity (all or nothing saved), check first if it is present to avoid the exception being thrown.

Answer (score -1):

If you debug the code and see what's the state of persistence context you may get your answer. You are right hibernate maintains a queue of sorts i.e. all the queries that are made during a transaction will run on commit/flush.

Please post the value of persistence context you get while debugging.